# How to read and write into MemoryMapped file from c# application to javascipt (shared the data between c# application to webpage through javascript )

Tags: javascript, c#, html, web

I need shared memory communication between c# application and webpage through javascript

```
public partial class FormMemoryWritter : Form
{
    MemoryMappedFile _memoryFIle;
    public FormMemoryWritter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _memoryFIle = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("myFile", int.MaxValue);
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtBox.Text);

            var accessor = _memoryFIle.CreateViewAccessor(0, bytes.Length);

            accessor.WriteArray<byte>(0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);



        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             
        }
    }
}
```

Above code use in c# applicaion but how to received that that data in webpage through javascript

Comment: You can't. There is no API that allows you to do it from inside a webpage. And even if it were possible, you'd only be able to actually map to memory on the local computer, and the local computer and the server are most likely not the same physical machine. It is possible inside JS runtimes like Node or Deno, but not from a webpage. If you need to send and receive data in real time, I'd recommend you use something like SignalR or raw WebSockts directly

Comment: I would send binary data as a MIME attachment instead of converting to text.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: I am using a single html webpage on local system . On that local machine my c# application is also run after that I want to shared c# application data  through  memory map.. (not through websocket,SignalR )